# How to bring an image to front?

Tags: android, image, animation, view

I'm translating an image from somewhere to another, and where it goes there is a button. But i want it to be unclickable when the image's over it! It's not seen but still can be clicked! How can i bring the image to front, so the button will not be worked? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.my_btn);
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Implement `setAnimationListener` in your translate animation and in `onAnimationStart(Animation animation)` put your `bringToFront()` method. It does work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think it could help if you make that the `ImageView` clickable. 
This could be achieved by:

- Setting the `clickable` attribute (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:clickable) to true in the layout XML
- Invoking `setClickable(true)` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29) on the `ImageView` object in your code

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood your question - could you provide some more details on the layout you are working with, how is the image represented/drawn, and what exactly to you mean translated (e.g. is it a translate operation on canvas?)

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your xml file.  The Views that are listed first will be behind the Views that are listed after them.

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv01"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/btn01"/>
```

In the code above the button will be placed on top of the ImageView.

```
<Button android:id="@+id/btn01"/>
<ImageView android:id="@+id/iv01"/>
```

In the code above the ImageView will be placed on top of the Button.

You can also hide the Button from the layout in your .java (Activity) file.

```
Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn01);
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Also you can set the Butt

Comment: As sniper suggests you can also set it to View.INVISIBLE, but setting it to View.GONE means the button won't take up any space in the layout.